# Is it possible to have Twig force render broken bracket variables {{ example } instead of throwing an exception?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, templates, twig

I am using Twig to render customer generated templates. If a customer misses a closing bracket:

Currently, twig throws a \Twig_Error and returns a message:

`Unexpected "}" in "custom-template-render5b91be77b99485.95837275" at line 2.`

Would it be possible to have Twig render as many variables as it can get (presumably the beginning ones in the template) and then just abandon after getting rogue brackets?

```
$parameters = [
  'mine' => 'sentence', 
  'variable' => 'broken',
  'another' => 'broken',
];
$templateString  = "Here is my {{ mine }} with a broken {{ variable } and {{ another }}";
echo $twigEngine->render($templateString, $parameters);
```

The above shows a missing closing second bracket. It would be great if the output was:

```
"Here is my sentence with a broken {{ variable } and {{ another }}"
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Would it not be _far_ more simple to just fix the broken template? Another crazy thought: validate your templates before shipping them to avoid issues like this leaking out of dev.

Comment: Test the template against dummy data before accepting it

Comment: @Sammitch these are end user generated templates. So thanks for the sarcasm?

Comment: @Devon is actually on to something. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Validate your user input before saving it

```
$error = null;
try {
    $twigEngine->render($templateString, $parameters);
}catch(\Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}

if ($error) {
    //display error
}else{
    //save customer template        
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `$error->getMessage()` is not very helpful in this case as the only message returned is something like `Unexpected "}"`. The line number is always 2.

Currently on failure, I am currently just falling back to display the content without being interpolated by the Twig engine to the user instead of blowing up the whole page for them.

Comment: Validating before it makes it to the database though might be the answer though. Thank you.